# CURL in Python or Django

Tags: python, json, django, curl

What's the alternative of doing this, in Python?

```
  curl -X POST \
         -H 'accept: application/json' \
         -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
         'https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token' \
         -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
         -d 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
         -d 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET'
```

And the JSON response is something like this:

```
Status code: 200 OK
{
    "access_token": "TU_ACCESS_TOKEN",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 10800,
    "scope": "...",
    "refresh_token": "REFRESH_TOKEN"
}
```

Anyone knows how can I get the access_token? Not the entire JSON, I only need the access_token.

Thanks

Comment: Why not parse the JSON to a dictionary then get the token by key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
import httplib
import urllib

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.mercadolibre.com")
conn.request("POST", "/oauth/token", urllib.urlencode({
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
    "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET",
  }), {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
conn.getresponse()
```

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a [Python library](http://developers.mercadolibre.com/python-sdk/) for MercadoLibre which wraps all that up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Look here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ requests library is good enough.